# How do I make a chrome extension to edit the text in certain classes

Tags: html, css, web, google-chrome-extension, browser

Can't figure out how to edit text or class details in the CSS of my chrome extension

I have been trying to make a chrome extension for a separate website, but while testing on google I wasn't able to get it working. I tried to just find the class or ID name and put my own CSS code to deploy with the extension, but it isn't working. The code is below

```
#SIvCob {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;


}

#SIvCob:after {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  color: aqua;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "replacement text";
}
```

Here is the HTML for that section on the google home page, as well as the CSS

```
<div id="SIvCob">
   "Google offered in: "
   <a href="https://www.google.com/setprefs?    sig=0__LK9AHKWnH4ZG4PCUbgFVKy7YEc%3D&amp;hl=fr&amp;source=homepage&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj39tjb4ueBAxVzHjQIHarGDVkQ2ZgBCBc">Français</a>
</div>
```

```
#SIvCob {
    color: #bdc1c6;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

.

Comment: "Workng" is too vague, you need to describe what should happen and what happens instead (use devtools to inspect the code of your extension and its effects). If you use Opera browser note that it forbids extensions on the search page, so you'll have to enable it manually in chrome://extensions page.